# 'does not appear to be a git repository' error when deploying subtree to remote

Tags: git, deployment, git-subtree

I'm trying to use git subtree to deploy site files to a remote server at dreamhost, but it goes sideways at the end. Here's what I did.

Made a directory for the repo:

```
mkdir iliumsite.git
```

In that directory, made a new bare repo:

```
git init --bare
```

Set up the post-receive hook. Still in this directory, created a new post-receive file in nano, with the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=~/f.ilium.com git checkout -f
```

Made the hook executable:

```
chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

Added the remote on local machine:

```
git remote add dreamhost ssh://ilium_shell@ilium.com/~/iliumsite.git
```

So now I should be ready to push my /dist folder with subtree:

```
git subtree push --prefix dist/ dreamhost master
```

This causes the following output:

```
Computer:bootstrap mattk$ git subtree push --prefix dist/ dreamhost master
git push using:  dreamhost master
-n 1/      90 (0)
-n 2/      90 (1)
-n 3/      90 (2)
-n 4/      90 (3)
-n 5/      90 (4)
-n 6/      90 (5)
-n 7/      90 (6)
-n 8/      90 (7)
-n 9/      90 (8)
-n 10/      90 (9)
… MORE OF THIS…
-n 86/      90 (85)
-n 87/      90 (86)
-n 88/      90 (87)
-n 89/      90 (88)
-n 90/      90 (89)
ilium_shell@ilium.com's password: 
fatal: '~/iliumsite.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Computer:bootstrap mattk$
```

It starts to execute, but then suddenly determines this isn't a git repo. Can't seem to pinpoint where things went wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would start by hardcoding the paths instead of using ~ and see if you get the same results

Comment: Good suggestion, Andrew. Unfortunately, I did indeed try that and got the same result.